# Query posts from a specific category and selected tag

Tags: posts, query, tags

I am trying to have a page (tag page) with this conditions:

- query posts from a specific category (for example : products)
- show only the posts with a selected tag (the tag is variable) not all the posts from that category.

Comment: You're using the **tag archive index** page? Do you always want to limit the query to the specified category, or only under certain conditions? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: @ChipBennett yes. i have tag , archive and index. i have a page with a list of some tags. i need when a user click on the tag it shows the list of all posts with clicked tag.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with the tag archive index page query, this really won't be all that difficult. You simply need to filter the query parameters at `pre_get_posts`, using your criteria.

For example:

```
function wpse137627_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    // If this is the tag archive index,
    // and is the main query
    if ( is_tag() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        // Limit the query to the specified category
        // Change '123' (int) to the appropriate category ID
        $query->set( 'cat', 123 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse137627_pre_get_posts' );
```

You can also pass the category *slug*, using `$query->set( 'category_name', 'cat-slug' )`.